# how to get the value from HTML to SVG file

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

how to get the value from HTML to svg file. (ie) i have to fix on one text box and command button in html then click the button the values on goes to SVG and print that text. My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kbtQB/2/).
what type of mistake (or) error in my code.

Answer (score 1):

**In html file you add this with url....

```
<object type="picture/svg+xml" data="menu.svg param=value&param1=value1"></object>**
```